# How to know selected values in each new widget separately?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my `Vue.js` application I have array called `filters`. That array has such structure:

```
[
    {
        "side": "R",
        "filter_id": 1,
        "filter_name": "gender",
        "filter_description": "Gender",
        "filter_values": [
            "M",
            "F"
        ],
        "filter_description_values": [
            "Male",
            "Female"
        ],
        "widget": "checkbox"
    },
    {
        "side": "R",
        "filter_id": 2,
        "filter_name": "age",
        "filter_description": "Age",
        "filter_values": [
            "18-29",
            "30-44",
            "45-60"
        ],
        "filter_description_values": [
            "from 18 to 29",
            "from 30 to 44",
            "from 45 to 60"
        ],
        "widget": "checkbox"
    }
]
```

I parse that array and create widgets in the interface. I don't know how to know selected values in each new widget separately? Usually, I set some array in `v-model`, but in this case, I don't know in advance how many new widgets will be created, cause array is dynamic.

```
<template>
  <div
    v-for="item in filters"
    :key="item.filter_id">
    <v-card
      tile
      elevation="0"
      v-if="item.side==='R'">
      <v-card-title class="headline">{{item.filter_description}}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-checkbox
          v-if="item.widget==='checkbox'"
          v-for="(value, index) in item.filter_values"
          :label="item.filter_description_values[index]"
          :value="value"
          :key="value"
          v-model="?"
          hide-details>
        </v-checkbox>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  mapGetters
} from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: mapGetters('store', [
    'filters'
  ])
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to add one extra key to store your selected value. 
eg:

```
{
    "side": "R",
    "filter_id": 1,
    "filter_name": "gender",
    "filter_description": "Gender",
    "filter_values": [
        "M",
        "F"
    ],
    "filter_description_values": [
        "Male",
        "Female"
    ],
    "widget": "checkbox",
    "selected_value": null
},
```

When you do looping, your v-model is the **selected_value**
eg:

```
<v-checkbox
      v-if="item.widget==='checkbox'"
      v-for="(value, index) in item.filter_values"
      :label="item.filter_description_values[index]"
      :value="value"
      :key="value"
      v-model="item.selected_value"
      hide-details>
</v-checkbox>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I add extra key as you recommended. In fact, the user can select several values in checkboxes. For that's why I changed `"selected_value": null` to `"selected_value": []`. I am confused. How to take these selected values now? I want to use them in the request body of `POST` request.

Comment: It will automatically save inside, don't worry

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Let's say we have 2 widgets. I want to know the selected values of the first one only. What do I need to do?

Comment: The selected values is saved in your filters data. You can get the value from there. 
https://codepen.io/markcc/pen/JjoNRmw?editors=1010

Comment: It is necessary to understand in what widget the value belongs. I think it would be better also to send the name of the filter to the `getValue` method. What do you think about that?

Comment: I updated the codepen. Not sure is that what you meant?

Comment: I don't see any difference after your last update. Let me try to explain. For example, in the console, I see such result when I select some value in `Age` filter: `Array(1) "30-44"`. In the same time when I select some value in the `Gender` filter result is `Array(1) "F"`. How to understand which array belongs to which filter?

Comment: As you can see, I can pass value to my getValue method. Same that I can pass the index that I loop. From there, you can retrieve the item. 
I updated again, see you whether you can see from there

Comment: Thank you for your detailed example! That's exactly what I was looking for.